# Jquery Flot - make data more granular as user zooms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

So I am trying to devise a way to create a nifty chart in which the user can zoom.  I want to try to create an effect that as the user zooms, the data will become more granular.  For example, say we are looking at a count on a date/time.

when you're at default zoom, which is say 3 months, you will see 1 data point every 24 hours.  I am trying to get it as you zoom in, and see a smaller chunk for that data to get more granular.  Like if you're looking at a day, each hour will get its own data point.

Do you all think it's possible to achieve an effect like this using Jquery Flot?  I have all of the data broken down into hours at the beginning, it's just a matter of calculating how much of it should be shown.

I already have the zoom functionality working, but just need to figure out how to make the data change as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flot won't do this automatically; you would have to register a callback on zoom that iterates over the original array to pick out, i.e. every nth sample, then redraws the plot using the results.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking I'd have to do, I was just wondering if anyone has attempted it before, before I tackled it.  It could be a cool feature to add to the project if I can do it right...

Comment: The hard part is going to be coming up with the intervals to serve as the cutoffs for the data points.